# epstpdf package acting funny?

Tags: errors

When I compile a test.tex file, I can immediately generate a nice handsome pdf. This happens only when there is no test.pdf file. So when I try to compile again, it seems to take about 50 or so times longer. The console output seems to be getting stuck on epstopdf-sys.cfg. Im using texLive with Tex works editor. Here is a MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \begin{document}
  Hi, this is a test.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, if you make a folder with your MWE and a copy of one of the .eps files from the [mwe package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe), you can see if the problem happens for all EPS files, or just particular ones of yours.

Comment: Are you sure, that the `.log` file of your MWE contains the string `epstopdf`?